# sample yfinance api for python code to get and return recommendation_summary for a stock symbol to javascript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, yfinance, stockquotes

I am getting "Failed to fetch data for symbol AAPL. Status code: 403" response from the following code:

```py
@app.route('/get_recommendations', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_recommendations(symbol):
    url = f"https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/{symbol}?modules=recommendationTrend&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com&formatted=false"
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        return data
    else:
        print(f"Failed to fetch data for symbol {symbol}. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        return None
```

I am expecting to get recommendations for stock symbol from yfinance.

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP 403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) means you aren't authorized to make requests against the given endpoint. This is happening because the [Yahoo Finance API was shut down in 2017](https://www.marketdata.app/how-to-use-the-yahoo-finance-api/). The only way to do it now is via screen scraping, which is almost always a bad idea. That being said, there's an existing library for this: [yfinance](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance)

While I'm here, here's a slight refactor of your code that makes better use of Requests and doesn't print (which is a bad practice).

```py
import logging

import requests
from flask import Flask

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/get_recommendations", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def get_recommendations(symbol):
    try:
        response = requests.get(
            f"https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/{symbol}",
            params={
                "modules": "recommendationTrend",
                "corsDomain": "finance.yahoo.com",
                "formatted": "false",
            },
            timeout=5,
        )
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response.json()
    except requests.HTTPError:
        logger.exception(
            f"Failed to fetch data for symbol {symbol}. Status code: {response.status_code}"
        )
        return None
```